# Mathematical Olympiad Treasures Diophantine Equations Q3.46

Tags: contest-math, diophantine-equations

The question asks to find integer solutions to $4x^2 + 9y^2 = 72z^2$.

The solution states, as a first step, 'first notice that $x$ must be divisible by 3 and that $y$ is an even integer.'

Why is this the case? Does it have something to do with the factorization of 72 =($2^3 3^2$)?

Comment: Well, $3$ divides both $9y^2$ and $72z^2$ so $3$ must divide $4x^2$ hence $3$ divides $x^2$ hence $3$ divides $x$.  The other one can be handled in the same way.

Comment: Thank you, I should have seen that!

Comment: A link to the Olympics let. Still, there are some equations have?

Answer (score 1):

All primitive solutions of $$  p^2 + q^2 = 2 r^2 $$ occur with all three odd, and
$$ p = u^2 + 2 u v - v^2, \; \; \; q  = -u^2 + 2 u v + v^2, \; \; \; r = u^2 + v^2 \; \; \; .  $$
One of $u,v$ must be odd and the other even.

If you want positive variables you may just take absolute values. Your equation then has, with some integer $t$ that may be $1$ or larger,
$$ x = 3pt, \; \; y = 2 qt, \; \; z = rt. $$